How to implement a blinking led circuit that is dependent on its voltage input?
I am designing a circuit with two LEDs, where one LED will blink when the output voltage (Vout) is 5V and the other LED will blink when Vout is grounded. I am confident in the functionality of the first NE555 timer circuit (left), but I am uncertain about the configuration of the second NE555 timer circuit (right).
My concern is whether pulling Vout to 5V will ensure that the right NE555 circuit remains off while the left circuit is active. Will there be any complications if I pulled ground to Vcc instead of pulling Vcc to ground? I have already simulated it and so far it works however I haven't implemented the circuit physically yet.
Additionally, I am wondering if it is possible to design the circuit using only one NE555 timer to control two LEDs such that one of them blinks based on whether Vout is 5V or ground.


The NE555 can source and sink 225mA on its output pin so you could just use Vout to drive both LEDs in anti-parallel (assuming that Vout can also source and sink the LED current, or use a voltage follower).

Alright I got what you mean now. I was supposed to only connect the led in series with vout. Thanks!
